# Is there a shortcut to undo MacOS's spell check correction without completely disabling it?

Tags: macos, spellcheck

I like Mac's spell check in general but in some cases, it gets it wrong. Is there a shortcut to quickly undo its spell correction?

Comment: Have you tried Ctrl + Z immediately after the word is changed?  This is what I do and it works for my use case.

Comment: @fsb that works, you could put that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right after the wrong word pops up, just type <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>.

This will undo the 'incorrect' spelling and put the original spelling back.  I've used this in Catalina, Big Sur, and it works on the Monterey developer beta 2 (so far).

There's no need to use the mouse or trackpad.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Backspace or otherwise move the cursor back to the end of the word & it will show you what you actually typed instead. Click to accept.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is clicking to accept the only way to do it? Is there a keyboard shortcut?

Comment: I haven't found one, but it's not something I use often. The trouble with testing it out to try find if it might have a command is every time you undo a spell-check, it learns it, so won't offer on that word again, it will only underline it in red after you move on :\ Apple don't mention any key command - https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mchlp2299/mac